# How to save different versions of a Block in Magento EE FPC by adding session parameters?

Tags: magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I want to save and get different versions of a block output, based not only on different get parameters. I want to add session parameters (customer attribute) as caching parameter.

I checked the different cache processors and see only cookie values and GET params are set. I tried to overwrite it but i failed multiple times.

The version of current system is Magento 1.14.1 Enterprise Edition.

Any help is appreciated.